# Compile a fortran 77 file(MIAH.f77) gfortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to compile a .f77 file. Here is the command:

**gfortran MIAH.f77 -o test**

but I am getting the message below:

/usr/bin/ld:MIAH.f77: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

/usr/bin/ld:MIAH.f77:1: syntax error

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

What does this mean?

Comment: It means it doesn't recognize whatever is in that file. We can't tell you why, because we can't see what's in the file.

Comment: A possibility is that the .f77 extension is not recognized as being Fortran source (the most common ones are .f for fixed-format and .f90 for free-format source) and thus it is passing the file directly to the linker. Try renaming the file to .f and building again.

Comment: you might also try `gfortran -ffixed-form MIAH.f77 -o test`

Comment: Confirmed. This error from gfortran is purely due to not recognizing the "f77" file extension.  specifying -ffixed-form does not work, you must change the extension.   Oddly the linux man page says format is determined from the file extension, but nowhere actually says what the extension should be..

Comment: This command worked                                                                    'gfortran MIAHCODE.f -ffixed-form -fd-lines-as-code  -o a.out'

Comment: Another extension you could try is .for .  You don't normally have to specify -ffixed-form when it is .for